# phpinfo() does not work so I cant find php.ini

Tags: php, linux

I want to know where my php.ini file is on my server.. I tried searching it manually but it does not work. I also tried running

`<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

with no sucess... I get this error on the error_log when I run phpinfo();

> phpinfo() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/pakhokve/public_html/phpinfo.php on line 1

phpinfo.php  just contains this

`<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

I need to turn off php safe mode off. I can't do it because of this.

Comment: run `locate php.ini` on commandline. Are you in a shared hosting environment?

Comment: Or run `php -i | grep php.ini` which prints something like `Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php.ini`

Comment: If you have Cpanel, you'll be able to find out the _php path_ by looking at the left hand side of the control panel. If all else fails, ask your webhost.

Comment: oh sorry. I forgot to mention that I'm using a windows computer. and this problem comes up with my paid hosting which costumer service is horrible. I can't run those commands can I?

Comment: Horrible customer service and little functionality? - I'd be voting with my feet!

Comment: Quick tip: talk to your host about this. Second tip: 95% chance they're not going to turn off safe mode.

Comment: Just because YOU use a windows computer doesn't mean the server is windows. The path in your error looks like a linux path.

Comment: there is lots of dupes for that. Please use the search function before asking questions. Find your answer in http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=find+php.ini

Comment: The server is Linux, my computer is Windows.  I cant access ssh and put that command because putty gives me a "connection refused" error

Comment: Well your best bet is to call them. If they have safe_mode on, I'm sure they disabled ssh as well.

Comment: voting down my question doesn't seem fair... those question are nothing like mine.. I cant access ssh nor use phpinfo() which makes really difficult finding the php.ini file.  I'll just have to rely on the horrible costumer service this hosting offers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/etc/php.ini
```

Or here:

```
/etc/php/php.ini
/etc/php5/php.ini
```

Or here:

```
/usr/bin/php5/bin/php.ini
```

Anyway, you can always find any file named php.ini in this manner

```
find / -name php.ini
```

but I would recommend

```
locate php.ini
```

Note: Sometimes it will be php.ini.default

Comment: Depending on the distro, who packaged it, what day of the week it was, or what the voices in their head were saying at compile time the php.ini can be literally *anywhere*. PHP is fun!

Comment: @Sammitch That is entirely true.

Comment: Just searched those directories.. found nothing. thanks

Answer (score 0):

On the command line: `php -i | grep 'Loaded'`

If that still won't get it you'll likely need root permissions to run this, but then again you'll probably need root permissions to edit php.ini: `find / -name php.ini`

Comment: I cant access ssh and put that command putty gives me a "connection refused" error

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `/etc/php.ini` and/or placing a php.ini in your site root?

Comment: Don't know what you mean by site root, but I hope you are not refering to the doc root.